# Php "echo" doesn't work properly with "onmouseover" event

Tags: php

I have this code that is supposed to echo some values from a MySQL database. I use the exact same code twice, and that specific part of the code doesn't work as expected.

I have a DIV which changes content on mouseover (with `$(this).html('')`).

Basically we have something like:

```
echo "<a href=\" event.php?id=".$donnees['event_ID']." \">";
echo "<div class=\"" ;
//here, check which category we have, and select the appropriate CLASS (DP_0, _1, _2, _3).
if ($donnees['event_category'] == 'universitaire') {
    echo "DP_0";
} else if ($donnees['event_category'] == 'sociol') {
    echo "DP_1";
} else if ($donnees['event_category'] == 'artiste') {
    echo "DP_2";
} else if ($donnees['event_category'] == 'aventurier') {
    echo "DP_3";
} else {
    echo "DP_0";
}
echo "\" id=\"".$donnees['event_ID']."\" onmouseover=\"$(this).html('";
echo "Institution: ".$donnees['event_institution']. "</br>";
echo "Association: ".$donnees['event_association']. "</br></br>";
echo "')\” onmouseout=\"$(this).html('";

echo $donnees['event_name'] . "</br></br>";
echo "Adresse: ".$donnees['event_adresse'] . "</br></br>";

if ($donnees['event_payant'] == '0') {
    echo "PAYANT"; //Works
    echo "<p>BLABLA</p></br'>"; // Works
    echo "<p style=\"background-color:red;\”>BLABLA</p></br>"; // doesn't work
}


echo "')\" sty1e=\" ";
//here, check which category we have, and select the appropriate background
if ($donnees['event_category'] == 'universitaire') {
    echo "background-image:url('images/universitaireCategory.png');";
} else if ($donnees['event_category'] == 'sociol') {
    echo "background-image:url('images/socialCategory.png');";
} else if ($donnees['event_category'] == 'artiste') {
    echo "background-image:url('images/artisteCategory.png');";
} else if ($donnees['event_category'] == 'aventurier') {
    echo "background-image:url('images/aventurierCategory.png');";
} else {
    echo "background-image:url('images/universitaireCategory.png');";
}
echo " \"> ";
```

I commented the weird part. If I do:

```
echo "<p>BLABLA</p></br>"; // That code works fine
```

but:

```
echo "<p style=\"background-color:red;\">BLABLA</p></br>"; // doesn't work
```

As soon as I add something with `\"\"` or `' '`, everything that is after is broken. Why?

The exact same code later in my code works:

```
<div> <p style=\"background-color:red;\">BLABLA</p></br> </div>
```

Comment: What does your rendered html look like when you do a view source ?

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the fact that the problematic html is encapsulated in `onmouseover=""` PHP is echoing out `\"` as `"` and the resulting html is something like:

`onmouseover="$(this).html('<p style="background-color:red">BLABLA</p></br>')"`

as a result, `onmouseover` actually only equals `"$(this).html('<p style="`.

To get it to work, you would have to escape your double quotes in the PHP *and* Javascript parts of your code. Unfortunately I've no idea how to do that.

I set up a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/eLPbQ/) which I hope demonstrates my point.

Comment: The double-quoting would be `\\\"`. That's "PHP, print a backslash then a quotation mark". This causes JS to see an escaped quote.

Comment: @magicalex Really useful!  I managed to fix my problem by adopting another solution (changing the content of a span on mouseover instead of my entire Div - cl.ly/DknB). I was being curious and tried that with my old code, and that actually worked! Will use that in the future! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A few things.

- Don't say "it doesn't work". Please describe how. I'm sure if your grandmother called you to tell you that her "computer doesn't work", you'd have to ask a mess of questions to fix it.
- You generally shouldn't generate Javascript using PHP code like you are. Instead, write one set of JS, and then send it different *data* (JSON, perhaps?) from the PHP. It makes debugging easier and the code cleaner, plus you can serve the JS from a different source - and you can unit test the Javascript!
- Your code is vulnerable to XSS attacks if the data you're putting into the JS contains any user-provided input. What if the `event_name` were to be something like `!"--;;^$&\\\*$'#`? Would the JS you generated still be syntactically correct?
- Do not use the `style` attribute where you can avoid it. Use stylesheets and classes instead. It makes debugging, maintaining, and re-skinning your site easier.
- You may avoid having to escape your quotation marks by using single quotes around the string, since in PHP either type of quote is valid. Note that variables won't be interpolated inside single-quoted strings.
- `</br>` is not a valid tag. Try `<br />`, which is valid HTML and XHTML.
- There is nothing wrong with your `echo` statement. It will produce the following HTML in the output document: `<p style="background-color:red;">BLABLA</p></br>`. The problem is elsewhere, but I do not have enough information to say where. Most likely your generated JS is throwing errors: take a look at the developer console in Google Chrome, and inspect the generated Javascript for errors caused by incorrectly injecting input into the code. Then, when that is the problem, do what I suggested earlier and write a JS function that takes *input* from PHP, instead of a JS function which is *written* by PHP.

Comment: These are more comments/suggestions, not an actual answer.

Comment: @j08691 I tried to write the answer which would be most useful to future Internet users reading this page. Many people copy examples without understanding them - if I just said "the problem is X", they would happily follow in the author's footsteps and run into the same problems soon.

Comment: I think it's a great post, following this advice and refactoring would probably solve the problem, if it wasn't actually caused by a typo... But I agree that it walks the line of what's considered an "answer" on SO.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not good advice, just that it's more of a comment/suggestion than an answer.

Comment: @Borealid Thanks for the feedback! I am fairly new to web development, very useful! I managed to fix my problem (Which according to my Grandma, was that all the following code was not called properly, I could see the rest of my code inside the div on the user side) by adopting another solution (changing the content of a span on mouseover instead of my entire Div - http://cl.ly/DknB). I will look into what you told me to improve the existing code!

Answer (score 3):

Somehow, a "curly quote" ended up in your code:

```
echo "<p style=\"background-color:red;\”>BLABLA</p></br>";
//                                    ^^^
```

This will produce broken HTML.

```
<p style="background-color:red;\”>BLABLA</p></br>
```

Replace it with a normal double quote:

```
echo "<p style=\"background-color:red;\">BLABLA</p></br>";
```

Comment: Ah! I looked at his posted screenshot. In his font there's no visible difference between the quote characters...

Comment: This might not be it (example 2 doesn't show it), but I don't know how else a random curly quote would have ended up in the post unless it was there to begin with. Séraphin: "View HTML Source" next time - the problem would have been spotted quickly.

Comment: Oups ok! Thanks for the help! Didn't even think of posting the user's generated html! On my side, there was no curly quote, it was done while porting my code to stackoverflow! (I posted a screenshot at first and someone took the time to edit my original post)